# Google App Engine: Is there any way to block HTTP calls instead of redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: go, google-app-engine

I've developed an REST service using Golang Chi framework and deployed the same in Google Cloud Platform App Engine Standard environment.
I've used `secure:always` in **app.yaml** so API always serves in HTTPS. But I want to completely disable HTTP instead of redirecting from HTTP call to HTTPS.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to disable it completely, but you can force a redirect to the HTTPS one.

If the endpoint runs in the App Engine Standard environment you just need to set the secure: always config for the respective handlers in the app.yaml config file ( Which you are already doing but there is ).

According to the [App Engine Standard Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_secure), the always value for the secure tag means that all the **Requests** for a URL that match this handler that do not use HTTPS are automatically redirected to the HTTPS URL with the same path. Query parameters are preserved for the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "disable", but you can return errors.  Remove the `secure:always` from `app.yaml`.  For incoming requests you can determine whether they are http or https and you could return a 500 error code for http requests.

That said, it is hard to imagine why you would want to do this...